# using awk sed to parse update puppet file

Tags: git, bash, sed, awk, puppet

I have a puppet file with a number of lines of code that has a section that looks like this:

```
$defaultrepo=myrepo
$defaultbranch=mybranch

gitmod::pullstuff {'othergitcode':
      gitcommit => "b54123be540adrwer3b65872384e0101c5f94c926b81",
      gitorg      => "${defaultrepo}",
      branch    => "${defaultbranch}",
    }

gitmod::pullstuff {'mygitcode':
      gitcommit => "b54123be540adrfer3b65872384e0101c5f94c926b81",
      gitorg      => 'awesomerepo',
      branch    => "master",
    }
```

It can have any number of blocks that will look similar to the two blocks of code listed above.

I am looking for a way to parse the file and pull out the values as variables then use them to obtain the lastest git commit and update the value. I was thinking of awk and sed in a bash script so that it can do something like this.
e.g.

`values could be:
    $gitrepo=mygitcode
    $gitorg=awesomerepo
    $gitbranch=master`

```
for i in $(awk "regexto pull out each block from  gitmod::pullstuff \{'whatever': through         to the ending \}" puppetfile.pp);
do
    $gitrepo="sed/awk to pullout git repo"
    $gitorg="sed/awk to pullout git org"
    $gitbranch="sed/awk to pullout git branch"
    $newcommit=git ls-remote https://github.com/$gitorg/$gitrepo.git refs/heads/$gitbranch
    sed -i "replace commit with $newcommit"
done
```

I am not a developer by trade so please bear with me. Could someone please point out what the general structure should look like. Don't worry about the regex etc I can mess around and figure that out. Just wondering how I can get it so that it treats each "block" it finds individually. For some reason I can't get awk to separate them out properly and it messes up the formatting.

Like I can do something like this:

`awk "/gitmod::pullstuff/{a=4}{if(a-->0){print;next}}"`

and it will pull out everything I want. What I need is to somehow stick it into a for statement so that I can treat each instance that awk finds as a separate block that I can do stuff too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you make your question more specific? "Any pointers" isn't a specific question. If you're not sure what to ask, take a stab at building a real solution rather than just pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I just made some edits. I guess I am just looking for what logical structure would make sense to accomplish my goal I can fill in the regex etc.

Comment: What do you mean by `sed -i "replace commit with $newcommit"`?

Comment: basically it will use the value created by $newcommit to replace the corresponding gitcommit in that block e.g. gitcommit = "b54123be540adrwer3b65872384e0101c5f94c926b81 could be replaced with gitcommit => "199561c5f55bb2e77bf022a6b294bs63f3c74d9"

Comment: I just added another edit. I am basically just trying to figure out how to get bash/awk to treat each found instance as a separate block that I can do stuff too.

Comment: +1 for editing question per comments. Good luck to all.

Comment: Is there a rule for when to use double quotes or single quotes in the puppet file? For example, it uses `'awesomerepo'` with single quotes, whereas `"master"` with double quotes..

Comment: That is actually a typo I usually use double quotes for everything. You can use single depending on specialness of the characters being used.

Comment: Ok then I will update my solution to assume double quotes.. Another thing do you need to use variable interpolation in the puppet file? I see that you define variables on the top of the puppet file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
awk -f m.awk puppetfile.pp  puppetfile.pp
```

where `m.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
    if (/^gitmod/) {
        gitrepo=getRepo()
        getline
        getline
        gitorg=getOrg()
        getline
        branch=getBranch()
        com[++i]=getNewCommit()
    }
    else if (/^\$[[:alnum:]]*=/) {
        vn=getVarName()
        val=getVarValue()
        var[vn]=val
    }
    next
}

/^gitmod/ {
    print
    getline
    sub(/".*"/,"\""com[++j]"\"")
}
{ print }

function getVarValue(a) {
    match($0,/=([[:alnum:]]+)[[:blank:]]*/,a)
    return a[1]
}

function getVarName(a) {
    match($0,/\$([[:alnum:]]+)=/,a)
    return "${"a[1]"}"
}

function getNewCommit(cmd,var) {
    cmd="ls-remote https://github.com/"gitorg"/"gitrepo".git refs/heads/"branch
    cmd |& getline var
    return var
}

function getBranch(a,br) {
    match($0,/"(.*)"/,a)
    br=a[1]
    if (br in var) br=var[br]
    return br
}

function getOrg(a,org) {
    match($0,/"(.*)"/,a)
    org=a[1]
    if (org in var) org=var[org]
    return org
}
function getRepo(a,rep) {
    match($0,/\{"(.*)":/,a)
    rep=a[1]
    if (rep in var) rep=var[rep]
    return rep
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is what I am looking for I am going to try playing around with your suggestion to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Luke I have updated my answer to include variable interpolation, and further it assumes double quotes. If you use variable interpolation, you must use the syntax `"${var}"` with curly braces, it does not recognize variables without curly braces like `"$var"`..

Comment: @Luke Note that you must change all single quotes to double quotes in the puppet file. You still have many single quotes there. For instance `'othergitcode'`..

Comment: Thank you. I can get around not using variable interpolation. This should work for me. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different take on your problem. If you store all this data in a YAML file :

```
gits:
  othergitcode:
    gitcommit: "b54123be540adrwer3b65872384e0101c5f94c926b81"
    gitorg:    "myreop",
    branch:    "mybranch",
  mygitcode:
    gitcommit: "b54123be540adrfer3b65872384e0101c5f94c926b81",
    gitorg:    'awesomerepo',
    branch:    "master"
```

Then you can have it on puppet with something like this:

```
create_resources('gitmod::pullstuff', hiera('gits'))
```

And this make it easy to manipulate in any scripting language (except `awk`, I suppose this answer falls short here ...).