# Parsing JSON-like configuration file using R or AWK

Tags: json, r, parsing, awk, template-engine

I need your help, as I was working with `AWK` many years ago and my knowledge is rusty now. Despite refreshing my memory some by reading several guides, I'm sure that my code contains some mistakes. Most related questions that I've read on SO deal with parsing standard `JSON`, so the advice is not applicable to my case. The only answer close to what I'm looking for is the accepted answer for this SO question: [using awk sed to parse update puppet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613771/using-awk-sed-to-parse-update-puppet-file). But I'm trying to implement a **two-pass parsing**, whereas I don't see it in that answer (or don't understand it enough).

After considering other options (from `R` itself to `m4` and various template engines in between), I thought about implementing the solution purely in R via `jsonlite` and `stringr` packages, but it's not elegant. I've decided to write a short `AWK` script that would parse my `R` project's data collection configuration files before they will be read by my `R` code. Such file is for the most part a `JSON` file, but with some additions:

1) it contains **embedded variables** that are *parameters*, referring to values of `JSON` elements in the same file (which for simplicity I decided to place in the root of `JSON` tree);

2) parameters are denoted by placing a *star character* ('*') immediately before corresponding elements' names.

Initially I planned two *types of embedded variables*, which you can see here - **internal** (references to JSON elements in the same file, format: `${var}`) and **external** (user-supplied, format: `%{var}`). However, the mechanism and benefits of passing values for the external parameters are still unclear to me, so currently I focus only on parsing configuration file with internal variables only. So, please disregard the external variables for now.

**Example configuration file**:

```
{
   "*source":"SourceForge",
   "*action":"import",
   "*schema":"sf0314",
   "data":[
      {
         "indicatorName":"test1",
         "indicatorDescription":"Test Indicator 1",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT * FROM sf0305.users WHERE user_id < 100"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"test2",
         "indicatorDescription":"Test Indicator 2",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT * 
                       FROM sf1104.users a, sf1104.artifact b 
                       WHERE a.user_id = b.submitted_by AND b.artifact_id = 304727"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"totalProjects",
         "indicatorDescription":"Total number of unique projects",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT group_id) FROM ${schema}.user_group"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"totalDevs",
         "indicatorDescription":"Total number of developers per project",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"data.frame",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${schema}.user_group WHERE group_id = %{group_id}"
      }
   ]
}
```

**AWK script**:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  first_pass = true;
  param = "\"\*[a-zA-Z^0-9]+?\"";
  regex = "\$\{[a-zA-Z^0-9]+?\}";
  params[""] = 0;
}

{
  if (first_pass)
    if (match($0, param)) {
      print(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH));
      params[param] = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    }
  else
      gsub(regex, params[regex], $0);
}

END {
  if (first_pass) {
    ARGC++;
    ARGV[ARGIND++] = FILENAME;
    first_pass = false;
    nextfile;
  }
}
```

**Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!**

**UPDATE (based on the G. Grothendieck's answer)**

The following code (wrapped in a function and slightly modified from the original answer) behaves incorrectly, unexpectedly outputting values of all marked (with '_') configuration keys instead of only the referenced ones:

```
generateConfig <- function(configTemplate, configFile) {

  suppressPackageStartupMessages(suppressWarnings(library(tcltk)))
  if (!require(gsubfn)) install.packages('gsubfn')
  library(gsubfn)

  regexKeyValue <- '"_([^"]*)":"([^"]*)"'
  regexVariable <- "[$]{([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:].]*)}"

  cfgTmpl <- readLines(configTemplate)

  defns <- strapplyc(cfgTmpl, regexKeyValue, simplify = rbind)
  dict <- setNames(defns[, 2], defns[, 1])
  config <- gsubfn(regexVariable, dict, cfgTmpl)

  writeLines(config, con = configFile)
}
```

The function is called as follows:

```
if (updateNeeded()) {
  <...>
  generateConfig(SRDA_TEMPLATE, SRDA_CONFIG)
}
```

**UPDATE 2 (per G. Grothendieck's request)**

Function `updateNeeded()` checks existence and modification time of both files, then, based on logic, a decision is made on whether there is a need to (re)generate the config. file (returns `boolean`).

The following is the contents of the template configuration file (`SRDA_TEMPLATE <- "./SourceForge.cfg.tmpl"`):

```
{
   "_source":"SourceForge",
   "_action":"import",
   "_schema":"sf0314",
   "data":[
      {
         "indicatorName":"test1",
         "indicatorDescription":"Test Indicator 1",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT * FROM sf0305.users WHERE user_id < 100"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"test2",
         "indicatorDescription":"Test Indicator 2",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT * 
                       FROM sf1104.users a, sf1104.artifact b 
                       WHERE a.user_id = b.submitted_by AND b.artifact_id = 304727"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"totalProjects",
         "indicatorDescription":"Total number of unique projects",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT group_id) FROM ${schema}.user_group"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"totalDevs",
         "indicatorDescription":"Total number of developers per project",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"data.frame",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${schema}.user_group WHERE group_id = 78745"
      }
   ]
}
```

The following is the contents of the auto-generated configuration file (`SRDA_CONFIG <- "./SourceForge.cfg.json"`):

```
{
   "_source":"SourceForge",
   "_action":"import",
   "_schema":"sf0314",
   "data":[
      {
         "indicatorName":"test1",
         "indicatorDescription":"Test Indicator 1",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT * FROM sf0305.users WHERE user_id < 100"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"test2",
         "indicatorDescription":"Test Indicator 2",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT * 
                       FROM sf1104.users a, sf1104.artifact b 
                       WHERE a.user_id = b.submitted_by AND b.artifact_id = 304727"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"totalProjects",
         "indicatorDescription":"Total number of unique projects",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"numeric",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT group_id) FROM SourceForge import sf0314.user_group"
      },
      {
         "indicatorName":"totalDevs",
         "indicatorDescription":"Total number of developers per project",
         "indicatorType":"numeric",
         "resultType":"data.frame",
         "requestSQL":"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SourceForge import sf0314.user_group WHERE group_id = 78745"
      }
   ]
}
```

Notice `SourceForge` and `import`, unexpectedly populated before `sf0314`.

**Help by the answer's author will be much appreciated!**

Comment: What is the question here? Are you in control of the format of the input configuration file?

Comment: @EtanReisner: The problem is that my AWK code doesn't work. The question, correspondingly, is how to fix the code. Yes, I'm in control of the configuration file. Regardless of whether I will go with the solution kindly provided by G. Grothendieck or not, I'd gladly accept advice on fixing my code as a learning experience.

Comment: What is `[a-zA-Z^0-9]` supposed to be doing? Matching the numbers, letters and the `^` character? When I run your awk script I get four warnings about unnecessarily escaped characters and a complaint about `nextfile` in the `END` section. What "doesn't work" about it for you?

Comment: @EtanReisner: `[a-zA-Z^0-9]` is a regex that is supposed to match alphabet characters (I thought that `^0-9` part excludes numbers). In my environment the script generates no errors or warnings, but produces no output.

Comment: So in trying to make your awk work I've found quite a lot of issues. You are trying to use the regex patterns as your keys in the params table but they never change so that will not get you at all what you want. Your regexes themselves need tweaking (at least here) for the warnings awk throws about them. You are setting the variable name as the value in your params table (because you never deal with the right hand side of the line).

Comment: `^` is complement range when it is the first character in the square brackets. So `[0-9]` means match any number between 0 and 9 whereas `[^0-9]` means match anything that *isn't* a number between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming the objective is to replace each occurrance of `${...}` with the definition given on the star lines.  In the post it indicates that you are looking at awk because an R solution was not elegant but I think that may have been due to the approach taken using R and I am assuming an R solution is still acceptable if by using a different approach it yields a solution that is reasonably compact.

Here `config.json` is the name of the input json file and config.out.json is the output file with the definitions substituted in.

We read in the file and use `strapplyc` to extract out a 2 column matrix of the definitions, `defns`.  We rework this into a vector, `dict`, whose values are the values of the variables and whose names are the names of the variables.  Then we use `gsubfn` to insert the definitions using the `dict` list.  Finally we write it back out.

```
library(gsubfn)

Lines <- readLines("config.json")

defns <- strapplyc(Lines, '"\\*([^"]*)":"([^"]*)"', simplify = rbind)
dict <- setNames(as.list(defns[, 2]), defns[, 1])
Lines.out <- gsubfn("[$]{([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:].]*)}", dict, Lines)

writeLines(Lines.out, con = "config.out.json")
```

**REVISED**  `dict` should be a list rather than a named character vector.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! You're right - R is fine, the solution appears to be even much more elegant than my AWK code (which most likely could be re-written to approximately match your R solution). Before your answer, I've never heard of `gsubfn` package - usually people recommend `plyr` or R base `*apply` functions. But, I understand why you recommend `gsubfn` :-). Thank you again!

Comment: Strangely, this code (slightly modified) started to work incorrectly, unexpectedly placing values of other (non-referenced) configuration keys before the referenced ones. I will add the code as a temporary update of your answer.

Comment: I just updated your answer with my code for investigation, but it mysteriously disappeared...

Comment: Posted my update with request to you for help at the bottom of my question instead of your answer. Hopefully now the update won't disappear. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Your attempt to modify my answer was rejected by the moderators.  Regarding the addition to the question, the driver code needs to be completely specified as well as the input. As it stands its not clear what is not working.

Comment: Just added UPDATE 2 per your request. Please let me know, if more information is needed.

Comment: There was a bug in the code. `gsubfn` requires that `dict` is a list in this case.  (If its character then it reduces to `gsub`).  Have corrected the `dict<-` line in the code.

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it! Being unfamiliar with `gsubfn` package, it would be difficult for me to spot this one fast. Hopefully, I'll become more familiar with `gsubfn` as well as your other package `sqldf`, which I plan to use further in my code. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  param = "\"\\*([a-zA-Z]+?)\":\"([^\"]*)\"";
  regex = "\\${([a-zA-Z]+?)}";
}

NR == FNR {
    if (match($0, param, a)) {
      params[a[1]] = a[2]
    }
    next
}

match($0, regex, a) {
  gsub(regex, params[a[1]], $0);
}
1
```

does what you want (when run as `awk -f file.awk input.conf input.conf`) for your given input.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This code looks much better than my attempt. However, it produces two errors: `awk:./parseConfig2.awk: line 9: syntax error at or near ,
awk: ./parseConfig2.awk: line 12: syntax error at or near next
`. Also, I'm curious whether your code uses one pass or two.

Comment: What awk are you using? It uses two. `NR == FNR` is a test for the first input file. So that block executes the first time (and `next` stops processing the script there) and the second time through the other block gets a chance to match. If you can guarantee that there will be a marker or that no definition will come after the first usage you can do it all in one pass.

Comment: Two-pass design is fine, I was just curious how it works. In regard to `awk` info, actually, I'm a bit confused by determining which `awk` I'm using. I tried various CL options (-W, -v, -V, --version, -version, etc.) to print version information, but to no avail. `which awk` produces `/usr/bin/awk` (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). I also have `mawk` and `nawk` on the system, but `awk` is probably best from the compatibility standpoint.

Comment: So that script above is gawk specific I believe (the third argument to match). I'm not sure what the issue near next is but that may be another compat issue (or simply a missing semicolon that whichever of [mn]awk you are using expects that gawk doesn't need).

Comment: To make the above single pass simply remove the `next` line. (You could also then drop the `NR == FNR` outer block and make the pattern match part look like the regex match part if you wanted to.) And then only run it with the input file listed once.

Comment: I tried adding semicolons as well as using `nawk` and `mawk`, but all three interpreters are complaining about the same line numbers (9 and 12). You're right that it's a compatibility issue: I just installed `gawk` and error messages are gone. However, the script doesn't output anything...

Comment: If there are two different ${...} on the same line this code will replace them both with the value associated with the first.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck True. It should probably use `a[1]` in the first argument to `gsub` to only replace what was originally matched. Though that still won't handle multiple replacements correctly. For that you would also need to loop over calls to match.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Which script? Called how? It works here (barring G.Grothendieck's comment).

Comment: Your script, Etan. Called as `./parseConfig2.awk SourceForge.json SourceForge2.json`. It works fine with identical file name args. I thought I could use different filenames for IN and OUT. Considering @G.Grothendieck's comment, I will go with his solution as more robust, but I appreciate help and advice from you both. It was good learning experience, albeit too brief. Would you be so kind to answer this (I'm sure very simple for you) `R` question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372758/subsetting-lists-via-index-vectors? Thanks much!

Comment: The two filenames aren't `IN` and `OUT` they are `IN` and `IN` (what you tried with your `ARG[CV]` manipulations to do in the first place (which might have worked in the `BEGIN` block by the way).